# how to get mysql full-text parser

Tags: sql, mysql

how to get mysql full-text parser from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

```sql
CREATE TABLE articles (
      id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      title VARCHAR(200),
      body TEXT
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE articles ADD FULLTEXT INDEX ft_index (title,body) WITH PARSER ngram;
```

```
SHOW INDEX FROM articles;
```

[reslut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/josaB.png)

Comment: Parse the output for  SHOW CREATE TABLE articles

Comment: `CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ft_index` (`title`,`body`) /*!50100 WITH PARSER `ngram` */ 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
`

Comment: @Akina It works, but it's not elegant